# How to perform a double step Subqueries in Django?

Tags: django, django-subquery

I have the below models:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Ledger(models.Model):
    ledger_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    group_name  = models.ForeignKey(Group,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,related_name='ledgergroups')

class Journal(models.Model):
    By              = models.ForeignKey(Ledger,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Debitledgers')
    To              = models.ForeignKey(Ledger,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Creditledgers')
    Debit           = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,default=0)
    Credit          = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,default=0)
```

As you can see the `Journal` model is related with the `Ledger` models with a `Foreignkey` relation which is further related with `Group` model.

My scenario is kind of complex.

I want to filter the `Group` objects and their balances (**Balances are the difference between their total `Debit` and their total `Credit`**).

I want to filter the total Group names and the subtraction of total `Debit` and total `Credit`..(**`Debit` and `Credit` are the fields of `Journal` model**).

Can anyone help me to figure out the above.

I have tried `Subqueries` before in `Django` but haven't done a two step `Subquery` in `Django`.

Any solution will be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Please add sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use annotations to calculate sums, averages, counts, etc. These annotations can then be used to filter on

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F    

groups_with_negative_balance = Group.objects.annotate(
    total_debt=Sum('ledgergroups__Debitledgers__Debit'),
    total_credit=Sum('ledgergroups__Creditledgers__Credit'),
).annotate(
    balance=F('total_credit') - F('total_debt')
).filter(
    balance__lt=0
)
```

Comment: Two annotation in one single query giving me incorrect output.

Comment: Its explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from django.db.models import Subquery
>>> users = User.objects.all()
>>> UserParent.objects.filter(user_id__in=Subquery(users.values('id')))
<QuerySet [<UserParent: UserParent object (2)>, <UserParent: UserParent object (5)>, <UserParent: UserParent object (8)>]>
```